# How to manage unit test to functions that require load files

Tags: c#, testing, nunit

I have a class having a function that receives a xml file and loads from disk an xsd file to generate html code.

I want to build a unit test what test it sending the xml.

The problem is that the unit test and the core app are in different folders, so the main function can't be able to load the xsd file from the disk because the relative path is different.

Comment: Can you provide some code of what you want to test?

Answer (score 0):

You can change your code so that the xsd is injected. You can also use MS Fakes to provide an xsd from your testcode.

Small example psuedo-code if you go for MS Fakes it might look like this:

```
public class SoftwareUnderTest()
{

    private void ThisDoesSomethingWithXSD()
    {
        var fil = File.Open(ApplicationDirectory + "\myxsd.xsd");
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class TestCode()
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test()
    {
        using (ShimsContext.Create())
        {
            // Arrange:
            // Shim DateTime.Now to return a fixed date:
            System.Fakes.ShimFile.Open =
                () => { return File.Open("\\Testpath\text.xsd"); };

            // Instantiate the component under test:
            var sUT = new SoftwareUnderTest();

            //ACT
            //ToDo: write your testcode

            //Assert
        }
    }
}
```

Injection is a little simpler as follows, but it does require a change in your code to allow for testing and it complicates the use of your class:

```
public class SoftwareUnderTest(string xsdPath)
{

    private void ThisDoesSomethingWithXSD()
    {
        var fil = File.Open(xsdPath);
    }
}

[TestClass]
public class TestCode()
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Test()
    {
        // Instantiate the component under test:
            var sUT = new SoftwareUnderTest("\\Testpath\text.xsd");

            //ACT
            //ToDo: write your testcode

            //Assert
        }
    }
}
```